# "Vrra" is a hispanization of which Russian word?

Tags: транслитерация, лексикон, приветствия

Mariano Payeras, a Spanish priest, wrote in an 1822 diary entry:

> As a last courtesy our officers said goodbye to all the Russians who saluted us with four cannon shots, hat waving, and gestures, crying out to us three times *Vrra, vrra, vrra*, which means the same as our "Adios" [goodbye] according to the interpreter.

What Russian word is represented by "vrra"?

Comment: I suspect that this is a typo. It was supposed to be "Urra" ("Hurrah"), not "Vrra". Someone at some point mistook U for V.

Comment: @AnT, the liturgical language of Catholics was and is Latin, which did not distinguish between the glyphs U and V; Payeras frequently used Latin phrases and terms in his writing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The salutation  **Ура! Ура! Ура!** repeated three times (троекратное ура) is a usual greeting in the army used during parades, official meetings and performed by a chorus of military men. While being spoken the reverberation of voices makes it as if several sounds of **р-р** were pronounced. The interjection corresponds to the English "Hooray! (Hurrah)" expressing joy.

Answer (score 4):

Hurrah!

From Russian Wikipedia:

> Ура́ — восклицательное междометие, употребляющееся в качестве
>   торжествующего восклицания, выражающего восторг, радость, общее
>   воодушевление, а также в качестве боевого клича. Кроме русского,
>   существует и в других языках (нем. hurra, англ. hurrah (или huzzah,
>   hooah), фр. hurrah и мн. др.) На письме чаще всего выделяется
>   восклицательным знаком.